# How to compare only Date portion in DateTime in LINQ to Entities (Case:- Dates are equal)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq

Its been a day now looking for the solution over google. But didn't find anything solving yet.

I have a form where I am using jQuery Calendar to Select **Start** date and **END** date.

```
public Nullable<DateTime> AssignedDate { get; set; }
```

Below is my LINQ

```
from c in entities.tDocumentStatus
                             orderby c.AssignedDate descending
                             where (EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.AssignedDate) >= EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(startDate.Date) && EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.AssignedDate) <= EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(endDate.Date))
                             select new ReportMapper()
                             {
                                 DocumentName = c.CheckoutFolderName,
                                 AssignedDate = c.AssignedDate==null? (EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.LastUpdatedOn)):  (EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.AssignedDate)),

                             });
```

It returns the right record till **Start** date is less than **END** date but when

> Start Date is EQUAL TO END DATE. It doesn't return the records(However there are records).

What's wrong with this LINQ.

## JUST Compare dates

Comment: So what are the values in `startDate`, `endDate`, and one particular `c` record that you say should be returned, but isn't?

Comment: @hvd `startDate` = {12/5/2016 12:00:00 AM} and `endDate` = {12/5/2016 12:00:00 AM}

Comment: `TruncateTime` normally strip out time part from `DateTime` value, check if generated query command includes `WHERE startDate = endDate` and try to run it against DB.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, Sorry!! I didn't get you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is my updated LINQ which addressed my requirement i.e., Exclude time portion from `Nullable<DateTime>` while comparison:-

```
from c in entities.tDocumentStatus
                         orderby c.AssignedDate descending
                         where ((EntityFunctions.CreateDateTime(c.AssignedDate.Value.Year, c.AssignedDate.Value.Month, c.AssignedDate.Value.Day, 0, 0, 0) >= EntityFunctions.CreateDateTime(startDate.Year, startDate.Month, startDate.Day, 0, 0, 0)) && 
                             EntityFunctions.CreateDateTime(c.AssignedDate.Value.Year, c.AssignedDate.Value.Month, c.AssignedDate.Value.Day, 0, 0, 0) <= EntityFunctions.CreateDateTime(endDate.Year, endDate.Month, endDate.Day, 0, 0, 0)
                         select new ReportMapper()
                         {
                             DocumentName = c.CheckoutFolderName,
                             AssignedDate = c.AssignedDate==null? (EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.LastUpdatedOn)):  (EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.AssignedDate)),

                         });
```

Here `startDate` & `endDate` are the method parameters.

Hope this helps :)